# List Validation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, custom-list, xslt, validation

[image]In attached sharepoint list column "Status" Data Type is "Number", Column type is "Calculated", 
Formula :-  `=IF(NOT([Balance Qty]=0),"OPEN","CLOSED")`.

Here the requirment is if "PO Date" is not entered by user, "Status" column which is showing OPEN(GREEN)/CLOSED(RED) should be blank which showing currently OPEN in Green Color in Test4

Advice please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF([PO Date]="", "", IF(NOT([Balance Qty]=0),"OPEN","CLOSED"))
```

You can chain the 'IF' statements inside of each other, since the IF function for calculated columns takes true and false arguments (`IF(<conditional>, <evalIfTrue>, <evalIfFalse>)`) -- you just replace an entire `<evalIf...>` argument with another IF

Here is an [excellent MSDN article on calculated column formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx) for SharePoint, they closely mirror Excel formulas but are not exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks John, Its work perfectly. And also thank to provided MSDN calculated column formulas.:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following?

```
=IF(AND(NOT([Balance Qty]=0),NOT([PO Date]="")),"OPEN","CLOSED")
```

Comment: Its not working.